# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Laravel method PUT not working

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-5.1

Basically I am using modal-dialog as shown below and I'm trying to get the method PUT to work. Unfortunately, I've tried either ways with _method="PUT" but it still doesn't work, anyone has a solution for this?

```
<div class="modal-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" _method="PUT" action="/manage_accounts/{{ $user->id }}" novalidate>
                   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                   <div class="form-group">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that HTML does not support PUT methods natively so you can't do something like this:

```
<form method="PUT"...
```

There is a workaround for this. Laravel accepts PUT, PATCH, and DELETE methods by adding a hidden input field. In other words, something like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/manage_accounts/{{ $user->id }}" novalidate>
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Notice that you are `POST`ing to the server, but you can add a hidden input field named `_method` for PUT, PATCH, and DELETE methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably PUTting to a GET route.

Make sure that the '/manage_accounts/{id}' route is setup as a PUT in your routes file.

```
Route::put('/manage_accounts/{id}', function()
{
    //
});
```